# Find the date when a bit column toggled state

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have this requirement.

My table contains a series of rows with serialnos and several bit columns and date-time.

To Simplify I will focus on 1 bit column.In essence, I need to know the recent date that this bit was toggled.

Ex: The following table depicts the bit values for 7 serials for the latest 6 days (10 to 5).
[image]

[SQl Fiddle schema + query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1559/2)

I have succesfully managed to get the result in a sample but is taking ages on the real table containing over 30 million records and approx 300K serial nos.

Pseudo -->

1. For each Serial:
2. Get (max Date) bit value as **A** (latest bit value ex 1)
3. Get (max Date) NOT **A** as **B**    ( Find most recent date that was ex 0)
4. Get the (Min Date) > **B**
5. Group by SNO

I am sure an optimised approach exists.

For completeness the dataset contains rows that I need to filter out etc. However I can build and add these later when getting  the basic executing more efficiently.

Tks for your time!

Comment: What version of sql-server are you running?

Comment: The sample is in SQL server 2008. However the original table is in a DB2 database. As I am more confident in sql server I am first trying on a sample in sql server sql then rewrite in db2 sql. Sounds weird or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
    select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sno)
    from dbo.TestCape2
)

select MAX(y.Device_date) as MaxDate,
       y.SNo
from cte x
inner join cte as y 
        on x.rn = y.rn + 1
       and x.SNo = y.SNo
       and x.Cape <> y.Cape
group by y.SNo
order by SNo;
```

And if you're using SQL-Server 2012 and up you can make use of [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), which will take a look at the previous row.

```
select max(Device_date) as MaxDate,
       SNo
from (
    select SNo
          ,Device_date
          ,Cape
          ,LAG (Cape, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno ORDER BY Device_date) AS PrevCape
          ,LAG (Sno, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno ORDER BY Device_date) AS PrevSno
    from dbo.TestCape2) t
where sno = PrevSno 
  and t.Cape <> t.PrevCape
group by sno
order by sno;
```

Comment: Your version is very clean Hatsjoem. I am still struggling to get it to work in my original db2 table but your sql inspired me! Thanks!

Comment: I don't got any experience with db2, so I can't help you with that sorry. If my answer helped you, do accept it.

Comment: Sure, the least I can do :)